# Ubuntu update: from Trusty to Xenial

Tags: 14.04, updates, 16.04

If I decide to update my 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS (without doing a fresh install of 16.04) will the software that I currently have installed be preserved?

Will I be able to use my current apps right away?

Comment: Yes, you probably will, although it's advised to a) wait for 16.04.1 or b) do a fresh install and restore from a back up

Comment: Like @grooveplex says : Wait. LTS versions like 16.04 are usually reasonable stable after 3 (-4?)  months. .... Besides that I'm not sure you can jump 4 versions, 14.04.4 - 14.10 - 15.04 - 15.10 → 16.04 ... Better do some research.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Upgrading 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS doesn't require intermediate upgrades

Answer (score 1):

Yes - the software will be preserved.

Yes - after a possible one or two restarts you will be able to use your apps right away.

I have gone through the upgrade myself a couple of times and it works.
Anything not compatible with Xenial will be reported prior to upgrade.

Backup all sensitive data prior to the upgrade, and whilst upgrading be patient and try not to interrupt or cancel in the midst of it because that's the sure and fast way of buggering it up.

If you're really worried, fire up a Trusty VM, install the apps you care about, through in some copies of the data you care about.  Then do an upgrade.  If it works ok, then there!  You've tested the process!  You can then apply the same method to the real rig.

Comment: How to avoid the jump to 16.10 if I want to migrate 14.04 to 16.04 ?

Comment: - Press the windows key on your keyboard and type "Software & Updates".
- Go to the Updates tab, where it says "Notify me of new Ubuntu version" choose "For long-term support versions".
- Now when Ubuntu next checks for updates, it will notify you of a new LTS version.  Just got with the flow from there.

Comment: Thanks. I've told you, but I'd need to do this from command line, because in my case it's server-related, is not about a desktop environment

Comment: You will need update manager installed.
I suppose an easier way to go through it is to just visit this page: "http://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-to-16-04/"  and scroll down until you see "Upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 – Server Upgrade". 
In summary however; do these in sequence...
1) $ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
2) reboot
3) $ sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
4) $ sudo vi /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
5) set the "Prompt" to 'lts' save and exit
6) sudo do-release-upgrade -d
7) restart all services when prompted
8) Reboot